# How to test/assert if an event is broadcasted in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing, laravel-events, laravel-broadcast

I am developing a Laravel application. I am using Laravel Broadcast in my application. What I am trying to do now is that I am trying to test if an event is broadcasted in Laravel.

I am broadcasting an event like this:

```
broadcast(new NewItemCreated($item));
```

I want to test if the event is broadcasted. How can I test it? I mean in unit test. I want to do something like

```
Broadcast::assertSent(NewItemCreated::class)
```

### Additional information

That event is broadcasted within the observer event that is triggered when an item is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can treat broadcasting more or less like events, so you can refer to [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#event-fake) of the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can achieve this with [Mocking in Laravel (Event Fake)](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mocking#event-fake)

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Events\NewItemCreated;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test create item.
     */
    public function testOrderShipping()
    {
        // this is important
        Event::fake();

        // Perform item creation...

        Event::assertDispatched(NewItemCreated::class, function ($e) {
            return $e->name === 'test' ;
        });

        // Assert an event was dispatched twice...
        Event::assertDispatched(NewItemCreated::class, 2);

        // Assert an event was not dispatched...
        Event::assertNotDispatched(NewItemCreated::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're broadcasting your event with `broadcast($event)`, that function will call the `event` method of the Broadcasting Factory, that you can mock, like this:

```
$this->mock(\Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\Factory::class)
        ->shouldReceive('event')
        ->with(NewItemCreated::class)
        ->once();

// Processing logic here
```

Not sure if this is the best way to achieve this, but it's the only one that worked for me.